# How to Detect User First Time Logging in Firebase on Web App Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to figure out how to detect a first-time login/signup to an account in my firebase authentication. I know I can create a boolean in firebase firestore, but that is very inefficient. There is a way to do it in android and ios using [`AdditionalUserInfo()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/additional-user-info). Does anyone know how to do this in javascript for a web app?

Comment: *"I know I can create a boolean in firebase firestore, but that is very inefficient."* - what exactly is "very inefficient" about this?

Comment: @DougStevenson, it isn't inefficient persay, but it would look ugly from a developer's side to have a boolean who's only job is to tell if the user has logged in before or not. It would still work, I just wanted to see if there was anything better in store.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call [`signInWithCredential()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#sign-inwith-credential) in your web app, it resolves to a [`UserCredential` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#usercredential).

This has an [`additionalUserInfo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#additionaluserinfo) property, which contains a `isNewUser` value.

Comment: Thanks, for reference to anyone, signInWithCredential() is deprecated, use signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential() in this fashion: firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(cred)
    .then(function(cred) {
      console.log(cred.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser);
    }); //where cred is the credentials you recieve from signing in

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment, I'm going to leave this here as well --

Darrow Hartman's comment in the accepted answer references `signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(cred)`, but that's not deprecated as well.

Instead, use `signInWithCredential(cred)`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithcredential

Comment: I think you meant "that's deprecated as well"